# can i modify an iphone app after being submited for aproval to apple?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Can i modify an iphone app after being submited for aproval to apple?

or I have to submit the app as exactly as is going to be on the app store?
and then I cannot change anything?

Thanks

Comment: Jasarian is right, but you can still change the price after the app is approved without submitting another binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the app after submitting it.

If you finish your modifications before the app is approved, uploading your new version will restart the approval process, increasing the time it takes.

If you finish your modifications after the app is approved, you can release it as an update.

However, if you're hoping to just sit in line while you finish your apps functionality, that is something you can't do.

You must submit a working, complete application - updates can follow later.